# Formatting Web API Result

Tags: .net, xml

I receive an XML result in Web APi as this:

```
<ArrayOfResult ....> 
<Result>
 <Id>
 <FirstName></FirstName>
 <LastName></LastName>
 <MiddleName></MiddleName>
 <Address1></Address1>
 <Address2></Address2>
</Result>
</ArrayOfResult>
```

Is it possible to format it as like this:

```
<Result>
 <WholeName>
       <LastName></LastName>
       <FirstName></FirstName>
       <MiddleName></MiddleName>
 </WholeName>
 <Addresses>
       <Address1></Address1>
       <Address2></Address2>
 </Address>
</Result>
```

Comment: No, for starters because XML element names cannot start with a number. Please read [ask] and elaborate on what exactly you want to happen (what do you mean by "format", exactly?) and what you have tried.

Comment: Edited the post. Don't focus with number, it's just a sample.

In WCF, I returned this result:

    <Result>
     <WholeName>
           <LastName></LastName>
           <FirstName></FirstName>
           <MiddleName></MiddleName>
     </WholeName>
     <Addresses>
           <Address1></Address1>
           <Address2></Address2>
     </Address>
    </Result>

using XMLElement.. Mapping it manually(setting element and attribute)

In WebAPI, is it possible to do it also?

Comment: @stuartd surely you mean "XSLT"? (And don't call me Shirley)

Comment: @Jeric so you have an XML input and want an XML output? Or do you actually receive an object as input and need to output another object, where the XML is an unnecessary intermediate step? Again, clarify what _exactly_ you want to do and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Appreciate it.

Comment: @CodeCaster yup that's what I meant.

Comment: @CodeCaster My bad for not clearing things up, the default output of my web api is the first format. 

The 2nd format was from my code using WCF which I am using XMLElement to transform it. 

Using Web API, should I use the procedure from WCF(XMLElement) or there are work around?

Comment: Show your code. Your Web API method now returns an `Result[]` array, it seems like. Then you need to create a new model and return that instead.

Comment: A plain code in Web API: 

public Inumerable<> Get() {
    // routine
    return list.Result();
}

my Class: 
    class Result {
        // FIelds goes here 
    }

I guess returning new model would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now have a result class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

And you return an array of that from your API method, causing it to be serialized as you show:

```
var results = new Result[]
{
    new Result { Id = "123", ... },
};
```

Now you want to change the structure of this response. In order to do that, you need to define a new type to hold the data in exactly the structure you desire:

```
public class Result
{
    public WholeName WholeName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> WholeName { get; set; }
}

public class WholeName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And map your results onto an instance of that type:

```
var newResult = new Result
{
    WholeName = new WholeName
    {
        FirstName = oldResult.FirstName,
        ...
    },
    Addresses = new List<Address>
    {
        new Address
        {
            Address = oldResult.Address1,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is it maybe. that's what I have in mind. just don't know if there's a/an annotations i could use or forgotten instead of creating those classes. 

correct me if annotations is a wrong term.

Comment: You can use annotations to change the serialization of a property, but you can't (trivially) introduce a whole new structure in the output (such as the nesting you require).